# AWS EC2 Instance Startup on Traffic Hit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running an ASP.NET Application on my EC2 windows server instance. I want to have my instance on stop state until someone access the application/url. I want to turn on my instance as soon as the first person tires to access it. All the help provide will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

EC2 instances, especially Windows-based instances, cannot launch that quickly.

Instead, you should look at a serverless architecture.  You can write your lambda code in .Net Core.